# Video streamer for android

Tags: android, http, streaming, video-streaming, rtsp

I want to implement video streamer in Android.Please suggest the suitable approach for the same.

Client side I am using VLC player to play the streaming video.

Approach :

1) stream the video using RTSP or HTTP protocol 
2) Capture the streaming video using VLC player (using IP address and port)

Queries :

1) Not able to get , how to stream video using HTTP or RTSP protocol in Android OS.

If you point me to specific code modules,it would be very needful

PS: 1) In my previous project I used VLCJ project to stream video from laptop.
PS PS : I NEED TO STREAMER NOT VIEWER

Answer (score 1):

[VideoView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) can set http path and play video streaming

```
  VideoView videoView = (VideoView) this.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
  MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
  videoView.setMediaController(mc);


  videoView.setVideoURI(Uri .parse("http://www.test.123/testmovie.mp4"));
  videoView.requestFocus();
  videoView.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Vitamio is very useful for this.

http://www.vitamio.org/en/

You can use the library, customize your player and play http, rtsp and many more.